# Changing A Range Like You Would A Variable

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say that I wanted to use the CountA(RangeFrom:RangeTo) function to see if there is any data in my range of cells. Is it possible to make the RangeFrom and the RangeTo into variables? I want to go down a sheet checking out a 20x20 box then looping into the next 20x20 box below it, with cells filled with text between the boxes. however I do not know how to put variables into the CountA function or if it is even possible so that I can skip over the row filled with cells that are full of text . If there is a way to do it, I may have not been wording it correctly resulting in me not finding any information about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

At the moment I am looping through my entire code using rows and columns, and just checking every cell individually, I wanted to know if it was possible to use CountA with a  variable.

```
Dim RowCounter As Integer
Dim ColumnTraversing As Integer
Dim PopulatedCounter As Integer 
Dim OverallCounter As Integer
RowCounter = 1
PopulatedCounter = 0

While (OverallCounter < 5) 
    ColumnTraversing = 1
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test") 
       While (ColumnTraversing <= 6)'column looper

           While (RowCounter <= 40) 'Row Looper
 '
               If (.Cells(RowCounter, ColumnTraversing).Text <> "") Then
                   i = i + 1
               End If
               RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
           Wend

           ColumnTraversing = ColumnTraversing + 1
           RowCounter = 1
        Wend
        If (i > 0) Then 
            PopulatedCounter = PopulatedCounter + 1
        End If
    End With
    OverallCounter = OverallCounter + 1
    i=0
    RowCounter = RowCounter + 2

Wend
```

This loops through a 6x40 box, then moves down and does another one checking if it is populated, essentially doing what the CountA function does but over multiple variables.

Comment: can you give an example of what you want?

Comment: Essentially wondering if I could put two variables A and B, representing Rows and Columns respectively, into a CountA function CountA(A:B)and update the range A and B as I go through a while loop.

Comment: Sorry can you be a bit more specific? Give an example of what you'd like A & B to be and what you'd like to change them to

Comment: A would be A1 and B would be F:40 so CountA(A1:F40), then I would like A to update to A42 and B to F82 essentially just looping through ranges

Comment: OK fine. two questions. Is it always going to be A and F? Also, why do you have `RowCounter = RowCounter + 20` in your code? Also shouldn't this it be ` While (RowCounter <= 40)`

Comment: Yes, it will always be A and F, and I meant to put 2 there instead of 20 to show that the row skips over 2 as in the example I gave you from A40 to A42

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195827/discussion-between-aaa-and-hakon).

Comment: Assuming I'm reading this right, it's 6x40 boxes running down the page with 2 row gaps in between each set. I'm not sure on the VBA code, but just the standard counta function would look like this, replacing the word "INCREMENT" with which box you want to evaluate (1,2,3, etc. I'm sure you could set this up to run through all variables): =COUNTA(INDEX($A:$A,(42*INCREMENT)-41):INDEX($F:$F,(42*INCREMENT)-2))

Comment: @Hakon, try the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments above, I am assuming you want to loop through boxes that are 40 rows * 6 columns and are separated by one row containing text. We can loop as such:

```vb
Sub Macro1()
Dim iRow As Integer, PCounter As Integer, numBoxes as Integer
iRow = 1: PCounter = 0: numBoxes = 0 'numBoxes counts the number of Boxes down the sheet

While (numBoxes <= 5) 'Change this to the number of boxes you have
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
        PCounter = PCounter + WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A" & iRow & ":F" & iRow + 39))
        iRow = iRow + 41 ' 41 = 40 rows of boxes + 1 row of text between bixes
    End With
    numBoxes = numBoxes + 1
Wend

End Sub
```